# header Content-Type não deixa usar HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho esse código para sobrepor duas imagens, uma em cima da outra

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['img'];
$user = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$mask = imagecreatefromgif('imgs/logo.gif');
$width = imagesx($user);
$height = imagesy($user);
$metade = $width/50;
$altura =  $height/3.4;
imagealphablending($user, false);
imagesavealpha($user, true);
imagecopymerge($user, $mask, $metade, $altura, 0, 0, 620, 360, 60); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($user);
imagedestroy($user);
imagedestroy($mask);
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="listra"></div>
    <?php


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Só que o

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

não deixando usar html,css teria alguma solução?

Comment: Uma solução seria você salvar a imagem em vez de mostrar ela na tela. Aí nao precisaria do header. `imagepng($user,'imagemgerada.png')` e depois inclua o 'imagemgerada.php' no HTML. Só cuidado com o cache. Dependendo do uso, pode por 'imagemgerada.php?contador incremental ou tempo' para nao pegar cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você envia um cabeçalho *Content-type* você não pode utilizar mais de um tipo de arquivo (imagem e HTML, no seu exemplo). Uma solução é codificar a imagem gerada em base-64 e exibir com uma [*data URI*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs), para isso é preciso controlar o *buffer* de saída de `imagepng()` com as funções [`ob_*`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.outcontrol.php).

No seu código remova `header('Content-Type: image/png');` e substitua `imagepng($user);` por:

```php
ob_start(); // liga o buffer de saída
imagepng($user);
$imagem = ob_get_clean(); // armazena o conteúdo e desliga  o buffer
$tagImagem = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imagem) . '"/>';
```

E dentro do `<body>`

```php
echo $tagImagem;
```

Answer (score 1):

A solução seria, salvar o script *php* como ficheiro diferente, e adicioná-lo ao script, como uma imagem qualquer.

```
<?php
// imagem_script.php

$img = $_POST['img'];
$user = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$mask = imagecreatefromgif('imgs/logo.gif');
$width = imagesx($user);
$height = imagesy($user);
$metade = $width/50;
$altura =  $height/3.4;
imagealphablending($user, false);
imagesavealpha($user, true);
imagecopymerge($user, $mask, $metade, $altura, 0, 0, 620, 360, 60); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($user);
imagedestroy($user);
imagedestroy($mask);
?>
```

Depois basta chamares essa imagem na tag img, para que ela seja exibida no corpo desse documento, porque devido ao `content-type` definido no header do script, este ficheiro, é uma imagem gerada via script, e possui agora o tipo MIME image/png, que é o mesmo usado em imagens normais.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="listra"></div>
    <img src="imagem_script.php"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, a imagem não aparece, eu pego o link da imagem que o usuario digita via post e envio para o imagem_script, acho q n daria certo...

Comment: Envias à partir de um formulário ?

Comment: Sim, somente um input onde pega o link da imagem .jpg

Comment: No caso a imagem a ser gerada, é a mistura de uma imagem qualquer selecionada localmente, e enviada à partir de um formulário ? É isto ?

Comment: Sim, ela pega uma imagem localmente, e depois sobrepõe sobre a imagem(buscada no link que o usuario digitou)

Comment: Agora funcionou, mas não teria como eu usar outro header só que dessa vez para retornar a home? ele gera a imagem no img.php e fica lá...